# What is the nature of the Square D QO Plug-on-Neutral Load Center recall?

Tags: electrical-panel

What is the exact mode of failure of the recalled Square D QO Plug-on-Neutral Load Center? Is the remedy simply to torque a screw?

https://wgntv.com/news/recalls/1-4m-electrical-panels-recalled-due-to-thermal-fire-hazards/ "The recalled panels were manufactured between February 1, 2020, and January 12, 2022, at Schneider Electric Plant 15."

https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/2022/Schneider-ElectricTM-Recalls-1-4-Million-Electrical-Panels-Due-to-Thermal-Burn-and-Fire-Hazards

Comment: Surely you have a link or something. [This one](https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/2022/Schneider-ElectricTM-Recalls-1-4-Million-Electrical-Panels-Due-to-Thermal-Burn-and-Fire-Hazards)?

Comment: Following @isherwood's link to https://www.se.com/us/en/work/products/local/safety-notices/2022/qo-pon-loadcenters/ leads to a description of the failure.

Comment: From the link of @triplefault "The issue detected is a loose neutral screw connection within the QO Plug-On Neutral Load Center. If that connection is loose, the affected load center can overheat, posing thermal burn and fire hazards." Is this a screw which was not tightened at the factory or one which would lead an installer to not tighten it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You know how I say "you gotta put your tanked water heater at 140F because bacteria", and everyone goes "nah nah, that's silly, lived my whole life with it at 110F and never heard of a bacteria death".  That's because the science on this is quite new (came out of the Flint fiasco).

This is the normal Kubler-Ross denial->anger->bargaining->acceptance curve.  (You are here).

The same thing is going on with screw torques. Engineers only figured out that screw torque matters about a decade ago. While electricians are still in full denial, endlessly grousing about torque screwdrivers (typical: "I have one on the truck, but it's still in shrink wrap") - or ignoring it entirely, with wholehearted support of like-minded inspectors.

So people go "Phbbbt, they're doing a recall over ***torque?***"

Yeah. They are. Because it matters.

Comment: I saw that too. What I find interesting is that they are recalling 1.4 **million** units due to possible problems after a single loose wire was reported! Which means either they think it is fairly common and serious - e.g., machines in the factory putting these panels together were set incorrectly - or they have a serious fear of lawsuits. Or maybe a little of each. But the good news is that it sounds like 1.4 million truck runs (presumably hired out to locals and not all done by employees) and not having to actually replace the units.

Comment: So, they're sending out electricians to check the screw tightness, not recalling the panels to the factory?

Comment: @Jasen OMG no, that would be horrible.  A service panel is made of 4 parts: a) bolts, b) the metal box, c) accessory ground bars (if equipped) and d) bus assembly attached by 2-4 screws.  The latter pops out surprisingly easily, so they would just swap that if there was a problem.